# Proof for non-positive semi-definite covariance matrix estimator

Tags: covariance

It is well known that the standard estimator of the covariance matrix can lose the property of being positive-semidefinite if the number of variables (e.g. number of stocks) exceeds the number of observations (e.g. trading days). I think the matrix can become singular. I have a clear idea why (inspired by the geometry of the problem) but does anybody have a short but rigorous proof for this fact?

Comment: Me and a colleague tried to prove along the following lines:Let $X = (X_t^j)$ where $t = 1,\ldots,T$ and $j=1,\ldots,N$ and $T$ denotes the number of observations and $N$ the number of assets. Assuming that $T<N$ and that the mean returns are subtracted we have $$ \hat{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{T-1} X^T X$$ and the claim follows as $$rank(\hat{\Sigma}) \le \min(rank(X),rank(X^T)) \le T$$ which implies $rank(\hat{\Sigma}) \le T < N$. Thus $\hat{\Sigma}$ is singular. Something more intuitive but still rigorous would be interesting.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to generate a positive semi-definite matrix

Comment: This is what I am saying. But an easier proof for it, that's the question. In fact the matrix is singular for sure (as its rank is too little).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard estimator of the covariance matrix is:
$$\widehat{ \mathrm{cov}}(X) = \frac 1 {n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)(X_i-\bar X)^T,$$
where $X_i$ is the column vector containing the $i$th observation of all the observables.  Each summand is an outer product of a vector with itself, i.e., a square matrix having rank at most one.  Therefore
$$\mathrm{rk\;}\widehat{\mathrm{cov}}(X) \le n$$
and the matrix not only can be but is always singular if
$$n \lt \dim X,$$
i.e., if the number of observations is less than the number of variables.

---

Edit: regarding positive-semidefiniteness:  $\widehat{ \mathrm{cov}}(X)$ is always positive-*semidefinite* because it is [Gramian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix), even if its rank is not full.  It loses the property of being positive-*definite* if and only if it is singular.

Comment: I appreciate your answer - but isn't it quite similar to the calculation in the question. Of course you added valuable comments and details. What I am looking for is a more financial/applied answer.

Comment: Yes, it is the same as the calculation in your comment, just summed out entrywise for each observation, although I did arrive at the rank inequality slightly differently.  So you are looking for a financial/applied sort of intuitive way to see this both rigorously and obviously....

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean - sorry that this didn't come out clearly. Something obvious and intuitive .. thank you!

Comment: A comment on your edit: this is important: I can have portfolios of zero variance but never ever negative variance ... that's the meaning in financial terms - right?

Comment: I think you're starting to get at something: in financial terms, if the number of observations is _less than_ the number of securities whose returns are observed each time, then it is always possible (in retrospect, of course) to construct a portfolio that would have remained constant in value during that time, but, as you say, it can never have a negative variance, unless you can trade imaginary shares on the stock market!

Comment: @JL244, yes, I think that's a nice explanation. Lets denote by $X$ the $T \times N$ matrix of returns of $N$ assets at $T$ points in time as above. If $N>T$ then I can find constant portfolios (as you say in retrospect). At the moment I can't do the algebra but this must be true. This means that there is a vector of weights $w \in R^N$ such that $X * w$ is some constant $c$ for all points in time. Thus the variance of this portfolio is zero. This is equivalent to a singular covariance matrix. I like this argument. Thank you.